# Dirichlet character proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $X$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $m$ and let $a$ be an integer such that $gcd(a,m)=1$.

Prove that $X$ maps an inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ to the complex conjugate of $X(a)$.

Could anybody help me out with this proof? I'm unsure on how to begin.

Comment: What kind of number is the $X(a)?$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the inverse of a complex number of absolute value $1$ is its complex conjugate.